# How to see differences between branches, after cherrypicking commits?

Tags: git, git-log, git-cherry-pick

On a git repo, let's suppose I have a master and a developent branch.

There are some changes going on on development branch consisting on several commits. I want to apply some of those commits to master, but not all of them.

For that reason I did the following:

- Created a new branch dev-cherrypick
- Cherry-picked some of the commits
- merged dev-cherrypick into master

However, If I now compare dev vs master with: `git log master..dev`, the output still shows the commits I already cherry-picked (I understand that this is because once cherry-picked, they get a new hash id)

Is there a way of being able to compare two branches to tell the *"real"* differences between them if some of those branches has cherry-picked commits?

Comment: Take a look at [git cherry](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git diff master dev`.